# remove elements from an list and then choose two random elements for a new list

Tags: python, list

I have a list `[(12,12),(1,23),(43,12)]`
how can I remove these elements from this list:

`[(12,12),(1,23),(43,12),(2,1),(1,3),(43,1)]`

so this list becomes

`[(2,1),(1,3),(43,1)]`

and then choose two of these at random to put into another list

Comment: Where do you get all of these list questions??? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import random

a = [(12,12),(1,23),(43,12),(2,1),(1,3),(43,1)]
b = [(12,12),(1,23),(43,12)]

c = random.sample(set(a) - set(b), 2)
```

Comment: I forgot order won't matter here, +1